# Accessing Android DCIM Images

Tags: android

How does one obtain images from the `/DCIM/100ANDRO` folder?

I have tried

```
 File rootsd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dcim = new File(rootsd.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/100ANDRO");
        File[] imagelist = dcim.listFiles(new FilenameFilter(){

        public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
        {
            return ((name.endsWith(".jpg"))||(name.endsWith(".png")));
        }
    });
        mFiles = new String[imagelist.length];

        for(int i= 0 ; i< imagelist.length; i++)
        {
            mFiles[i] = imagelist[i].getAbsolutePath();
        }
        mUrls = new Uri[mFiles.length];

        for(int i=0; i < mFiles.length; i++)
        {
            mUrls[i] = Uri.parse(mFiles[i]);   
        }
```

but I got a Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: get all images from the DCIM folder

Comment: where this folder are located

Comment: is DCIM folder are in assets or in SDcard? or any where else?

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/443531/Android/Mobile/display-Images-stored-sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to give the app permission to write the external memory? 
It is done in the AndroidManifest.xml file, by adding 
 "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Since you are making a new file object, this is needed, I would guess.

Comment: I have used "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: Okay, which line is it that throws the exception?

Comment: Try checking if `dcim.isDirectory())` before calling `dcim.listFiles(`

Comment: Find an example here on [www.anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/building_an_android_filebrowser_list-based_-t67.html)